# Parameter of the previous build for new builds

Tags: parameters, jenkins, parameter-passing, parameterized

My Jenkins project build configuration accepts a parameter to build. But this paremeter is changing rarely. Is there any way to set this paremeter from previous build such as ${LastBuild.parameters.myparameter} ?

Thanks

Edit:

Default values is not great because of the nature of our builds. Our builds are triggered by post commit hooks, developers and our custom scripts at arbitrary times. And manually triggered builds can be tedious and error-prone. Each time one has to check latest parameters or copy paste it to trigger.

Comment: Could you just set that value as the default for the parameter?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution that comes to mind.

1. Add a new task to you job's ant files and remember to call it somewhere:

> ```
> <target name="lastParameters">
>   <!-- choose a proper path and parameter key/name pairs -->
>   <propertyfile file="/lastBuild.properties">
>     <entry key="yourparameter" type="string" value="${yourparameter}" />
>   </propertyfile>
> </target>
> ```

Remember you can add multiple parameters to this file! Check the official [task help page](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/propertyfile.html) for details.

2. Remove SCM polling form the job
3. Create a new job that does SCM polling and has a build step that trigger/calls builds on other project and supply the project to build as your first job and add parameters from properties file:

[image: Example for trigger window]

This should basically rewrite the parameter to a properties file and then read it on build triggers...

Leave a comment if you have any issues